# Select DISTINCT and Select COUNT

Tags: mysql

An SQL query which I use seems to be having issue with counting the distinct selection. Here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.item_name,
                (SELECT count(c.item_name) FROM stocks c 
                WHERE a.item_name = c.item_name) as 'count' 
       FROM stocks a;
```

I have 4 rows containing `apple` and 2 rows containing `banana` in my database with different barcodes as follows:

```
+-------------+-----------+
|  item_name  |  barcode  |
+-------------+-----------+
| apple       | 1283123   |
| apple       | 1231231   |
| apple       | 1231312   |
| apple       | 1231312   |
| bananas     | 1231312   |
| bananas     | 1231312   |
+-------------+-----------+
```

Using the query above give me output of

```
+-------------+-----------+
|  item_name  |  barcode  |
+-------------+-----------+
| apple       | 5         |
| bananas     | 2         |
+-------------+-----------+
```

The query always adds 1 count to the first row. What is wrong with my query?

Comment: No, it doesn't: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f45a79/1

Comment: PHP is not involved in this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need a join at all? Using `COUNT()` with a `GROUP BY` will provide you with the same desired result:

```
  SELECT item_name,
         COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM stocks
GROUP BY item_name;
```

Comment: Apology sir thats the first thing i learned, this suits my code well :) .. but sir could you explain the cause of the wrong iteration?